# First Java solution on codechef give NZEC

Tags: java

I am trying to put solution to my first codechef problem. I am getting NZEC.

my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class HS08TEST{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cashwithdraw= in.nextInt(); 
        float balance=in.nextFloat();
        float bankcharge=.50f;
        float result;
        //Successful transaction
        if(cashwithdraw<balance && cashwithdraw%5==0){
            float amountleft=balance-cashwithdraw;
            result=amountleft-bankcharge;
            System.out.printf("%.2f",result);
        }
        //Incorrect Withdrawal Amount (not multiple of 5)
        else if(cashwithdraw<balance && cashwithdraw%5!=0){
            result=balance;
            System.out.printf("%.2f",result);
        }
        //Insufficient Funds
        else if (cashwithdraw>balance) {
            result=balance;
            System.out.printf("%.2f",result);



        }



    }
}
```

the error I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at HS08TEST.main(Main.java:6)
```

Comment: Looks like there's no `int` waiting on the standard input. Also, what's NZEC?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca No Zuch Element Exception. For angel: the stacktrace shows the error in line 6: `int cashwithdraw= in.nextInt();`. The class `Scanner` is a bit awkward as prior a `if (in.hasNextInt()) { ...` should be called, and `readNextLine` is needed too. Personally I would use a `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))` and `Integer.parseInt` or such instead.

Comment: @JoopEggen : Why it works locally and gives error on Codechef only? I was not able to reproduce this error on my host machine.

Comment: Extra newline, erroneous input.

Comment: class HS08TEST{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  int cashwithdraw= Integer.parseInt(inp.readLine());
        float balance=Float.parseFloat(inp.readLine());
        float bankcharge=.50f;
        float result;
        //Successful transaction
        if(cashwithdraw<balance && cashwithdraw%5==0){
         float amountleft=balance-cashwithdraw;
         result=amountleft-bankcharge;
         System.out.printf("%.2f",result);
        }

Comment: //Incorrect Withdrawal Amount (not multiple of 5)
        else if(cashwithdraw<balance && cashwithdraw%5!=0){
         result=balance;
         System.out.printf("%.2f",result);
        }
        //Insufficient Funds
        else if (cashwithdraw>balance) {
         result=balance;
         System.out.printf("%.2f",result);
         
        }



 }
}

Comment: I am getting error :  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

Comment: You can edit your quesiton and add the new/updated code there that is formatted, please.

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine. You problem is that when `Scanner` await for an integer value, you enter smth. else. You could check it with additional checks and return back until user enter a valid number.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    final float bankCharge = .50f;

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        scan.useLocale(Locale.US);
        int cashWithdraw = getCashWithdraw(scan);
        float balance = getBalance(scan);

        if (isSuccessfulTransaction(cashWithdraw, balance))
            System.out.printf("%.2f", balance - cashWithdraw - bankCharge);
        else if (isIncorrectWithdrawAmount(cashWithdraw, balance) || isInsufficientFunds(cashWithdraw, balance))
            System.out.printf("%.2f", balance);
    }
}

private static int getCashWithdraw(Scanner scan) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter Cash Withdraw: ");
            return scan.nextInt();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Invalid integer number.");
        }
    }
}

private static float getBalance(Scanner scan) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter Balance: ");
            return scan.nextFloat();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Invalid float number.");
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isSuccessfulTransaction(int cashWithdraw, float balance) {
    return cashWithdraw < balance && cashWithdraw % 5 == 0;
}

private static boolean isIncorrectWithdrawAmount(int cashWithdraw, float balance) {
    return cashWithdraw < balance && cashWithdraw % 5 != 0;
}

private static boolean isInsufficientFunds(int cashWithdraw, float balance) {
    return cashWithdraw > balance;
}
```

Comment: @angel Then check your question, because there's no reference to file. You use standard input.